# How many person/group can be saved in a person/group column?

Tags: 2010, people-picker, column-data, data

Is it possible to store some 1000+ users in a SharePoint 'person' column.

Answer (score 1):

A multivalue "person" column is a multivalue lookup field which should support unlimited number of selections. How rendering will work with 1000+ users is then a completely other issue and the time it'll take to validate the 1000+ users on edit will also be a issue

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft only mentions in the software boundaries and limits specification for SharePoint that this column can be added 96 times to a SharePoint List or Library (SP2013 and SP2010).This is the only restriction that's available from Microsoft about this column:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx

Otherwise you would need to test it on your own to determine the maximum number (if there is), and I don't think you would reach that number if it exists in real world scenarios, because if you were to add a large number of users to this column, it would be a better idea to add these users to a group and add this group in this column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean store as in available for selection? Yes, you can store around 2000 in a group and limit the people selection to that group.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/sharepoint2010general/thread/86acd7fc-d15c-46b6-8a78-8d113f55d75f

If you mean select 1000 people to put into that column, I don't know. It would be easier to select the whole group from a visual point of view whether it's possible or not